# i found this code for pure virtual function in c . can anyone please explain it?

Tags: c, struct

```
struct netdev_ops;


struct netdev 
    {

        struct netdev_ops *ops; /* C-style vtable pointer */
    };

struct netdev_ops {

        void (*free)(struct netdev *netdev);


        int (*send)(struct netdev *netdev,
                    struct packet *packet);


        int (*receive)(struct netdev *netdev,
                       struct packet **packet, char **error);
     };
```

can anyone explain the above code ?

Comment: What is the question? You need to explain what you do not understand.

Comment: There is no code for functions in this fragment. Just two definitions of structures that happen to reference each other, one containing function pointers that use a pointer to one of these structure as one of their arguments.

Comment: @joop For this code to make any sense, the second struct must be allocated in a different code module than the first one. That's how you usually do OOP in C.

Comment: I know that. As I said: the fragment contains only struct definitions.

Answer (score 2):

`struct netdev_ops *ops` is a pointer to an *incomplete type*, sometimes also referred to as *opaque type*.

This means that the file which is using the struct pointer has no idea what contents the struct got, nor can it access any of the struct members.

You cannot allocate a variable of incomplete type, just a pointer to such a variable. The actual allocation must be done in another code module (class) which knows the implementation of the struct.

In your case, the function pointers inside that struct are only known by the module that should know about them. Only that module (class) can call them.

It is very similar to a C++ abstract base class with all members set as private. You cannot create an instance of such a variable, just a pointer to one.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about pure virtual functions (except that I have heard of them in C++), and I am sure this type of classification doesn't exist in C.

In the following structure:

```
struct netdev_ops {

        void (*free)(struct netdev *netdev);


        int (*send)(struct netdev *netdev,
                    struct packet *packet);


        int (*receive)(struct netdev *netdev,
                       struct packet **packet, char **error);
     };
```

Three **function pointers** are declared: `free`, `send`, `receive`

Function pointer `free` accepts `struct netdev *` type argument and returns nothing.

Function pointer `send` accepts `struct netdev *` and `struct packet*` type arguments and returns an `int`. and so on.

To understand it more clearly you will need to study about function pointers in C and how they are used. These type of structures mimic the C++ `struct` member functions.

In the following part:

```
struct netdev_ops;


struct netdev 
    {

        struct netdev_ops *ops;
    };
```

`struct netdev_ops` was declared here (but not defined here) so that a variable (or pointer) of that type can be declared inside `struct netdev`.